# Ionic No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I trying to run a new ionic project but I have an error.
I'm trying to build ionic Android project on Android Studio and I get this error:

Event log:

```
Gradle sync started

Gradle sync failed: No installed build tools found. Install the
Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.           Consult IDE log for
more details (Help | Show Log) (24s 112ms)
```

Build

```
No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools
version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>       ...

Note:

1. In the terminal, the project build successful
2. A simple project (not ionic) build without problem on Android Studio.
3. the problem appeared after update gradle:
4. I have already:

   - Remove platforms/Android folder and add Android again:
   - Clean project
   - Invalid Caches/Restart
   - Check for updates

[image: SDK manager]

ionic info

CLI packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

Global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

Local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : MyApplication android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v10.4.0
npm               : 6.1.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/ines/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```